# How to add a condition "if the boolean field is wrong" to my module?

Tags: php, drupal, boolean, drupal-modules, drupal-8

Sorry for the layout, but I do not understand this new version of the site :-(

I have a site with Drupal 8.6 and Commerce 2.11

I created a custom module to customize the "Add to Cart" button in a store.

In my store type, I created a Boolean type field with the machine name 
`field_professionnel_panier`

I want to add a condition to my module:
If the Boolean field is false.

How to do this ?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Hook implementations of commerce_marketplace_premium_merchant module.
 */

use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\StoreType;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductType;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationType;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function commerce_marketplace_premium_merchant_form_commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $current_store = \Drupal::service('commerce_store.current_store');
  $owner = $current_store->getStore()->getOwner();
  $active_sale = ??????????
  foreach ($form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->getPurchasedEntity()->getProduct()->getStores() as $store) {
    $bundle = $store->bundle();
    // Store type professionnel.
    elseif ($bundle == 'professionnel') {
      if (??????????) {
        if (!$owner->hasRole('marchand_premium')) {
          if (isset($form["#attributes"]["class"]) && in_array("commerce-order-item-add-to-cart-form", $form["#attributes"]["class"])) {
            $selectedVariationId = $form_state->get('selected_variation');
            $selectedVariation = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation::load($selectedVariationId);
            $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Offline sales');
            $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = array('button--add-to-cart', 'button button--primary', 'js-form-submit', 'form-submit', 'is-disabled', 'btn-warning', 'btn');
            $form['actions']['submit']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if($field_professionnel_panier === false){}` ?

Comment: @executable Thank you, is it two or three `=` ? The first part is missing. There is 2 line in my code with ????????

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($field_professionnel_panier === false) {}
```

or if its in your store object:

```
if ($store->field_professionnel_panier === false) {}
```

**To answer your comment:**

== check if the values of the two variables you are comparing are equal

=== checks if they are equal and of the same type (i.e. boolean)

Comment: So thank you by taking my code, it should be `if ($current_store->field_professionnel_panier === false) {`. This code will check that the Boolean checkbox is not checked ?

Comment: I tested your code but it does not work. I have the impression that he does not find the field